# Can the range of a variable be inclusive infinity?

Tags: random-variables

Can a range be $[0, \infty]$ or must it be $[0, \infty)$ because you can never quite reach infinity?

Clarification: 
$[0, 1]$ means $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 $, while  $(0, 1)$ means $0 < x < 1 $. My question is whether infinity can be written as inclusive when stating the range.

---

Comment: $\infty$ is NOT a real number.

Comment: @AnuragA So, is that a no?

Comment: A function can have range $[0,+\infty]$, it's even usual in some area of the mathematics, but it's not a fuction with real values

Comment: @Tryss, so can we use the square bracket when stating the range?

Comment: It's a standard notation to say $\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{ + \infty \}$, so, yes, you can use it... but be carefull, it's not an intervall of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention you use $(-\infty$ or  $\infty)$, that is how you will always find it in the literature.

Comment: Yes, this was my question. Could you cite the fact that it's conventionally written with parenthesis and not brackets?

Comment: well no, but if you think about it, the attribute of ) that makes it differ from ] is already encoded in $\infty$. Infinity is not a point to be reached. Conventionally we use ().

Comment: May I suggest something? Try to phrase why you would want to write infinity]. This might help you,

Answer (score 1):

Generally if including positive and negative infinities, one says that one is working with the "extended real line", usually denoted $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$. It's quite possible, consider the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & \mathrm{if } \quad x\neq 0\\\infty & \mathrm{if }\quad x=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

An example of where this is actually used are measure functions. For instance, the Lebesgue measure, $\lambda$ on (certain subsets of) $\Bbb R$ has the property that $$\lambda((a,b)) =  b-a $$
when $a,b$ are finite, while, for example $$\lambda(\Bbb R) = \infty$$.

Answer (score -1):

Can it be $e^\pi$? $\infty$ and $e^\pi$ are just two entities that you may or may not consider part of a set. You can perfectly include them and define functions on that set or taking values of that set.